# How do I fix the error when adding Custom Settings?

Tags: metadata-api, customsetting, custom-metadata

My task is to create an LWC component and then add it to a managed package. I was told that to store the API and the key to it, you should use Custom Settings and Custom Metadata Types. No more specifics. Since I'm new, I assumed that the API should be stored in Custom Settings, and the key in Custom Metadata Types.

I added a new entry in Custom Settings:
[image]

Next, I try to add a new field and get an error. I understand that this is not how I write the path to my Custom Metadata Types record?
Here is my formula:

```
"the_api_is_specified_here" + $CustomMetadata.Weather_api_key__mdt.key__c
```

[image]

In here is my Custom Metadata Types record (which I am trying to refer to at the end of the formula):

[image]
[image]

Maybe I'm wrong and I need to implement it in a different way?

Comment: Something does not seem to match up.  You separately show `$CustomMetadata.Weather_api_key__mdt.key__c` as part of your formula, but the error shown in your screenshot seems to indicate that you have `$CustomMetadata.Type__mdt.Weather_api_key.key__c` in your formula.  Could you please clarify?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing [CustomSettings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_customsettings.htm) and [CustomMetadataType](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.custommetadatatypes_overview.htm&type=5) in your setup. It looks as if you wish to use CustomMetadataType and I recommend that.

Your formula to retrieve the key__c from Weather_api_key (CustomMetadataType) should be:

```
$CustomMetadata.Weather_api_key__mdt.First_Key.key__c
```

Your formula to retrieve the key__c from weatherAPI__c (CustomSetting) should be:

```
$Setup.weatherAPI__c.key__c
```

Comment: I was confused and thought the same thing at first, but I believe the OP might be trying to reference a Custom Metadata Type in a formula on a field inside of a Custom Setting.

Comment: @Moonpie I updated the screenshot with the error and described the essence of the issue in more detail.

Comment: Are you looking to use the Custom Metadata Type record as a Default Value on the new field in a Custom Setting? Formula Data Type field is not supported in Custom Setting so if you are picking this Data Type as the new field, your not creating it on a Custom Setting.